# C++ equivalent of Python String Slice?

Tags: python, c++, string

In python I was able to slice part of a string; in other words just print the characters after a certain position. Is there an equivalent to this in C++?

Python Code:

```
text= "Apple Pear Orange"
print text[6:]
```

Would print: `Pear Orange`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, it is the [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method:

```
basic_string substr( size_type pos = 0,
                     size_type count = npos ) const;
```

> Returns a substring [pos, pos+count). If the requested substring extends past the end of the string, or if count == npos, the returned substring is [pos, size()).

#### Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    std::string text("Apple Pear Orange");
    std::cout << text.substr(6) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[See it run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fb5358b669ce6b1)

---

If you can use C++17, use a `string_view` to avoid a copy:

```
std::string_view(text).substr(6)
```

---

If you can use C++20, now we have [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges). See other answers for more information.

Answer (score 17):

In C++ the closest equivalent would probably be string::substr().
Example:

```
std::string str = "Something";
printf("%s", str.substr(4)); // -> "thing"
printf("%s", str.substr(4,3)); // -> "thi"
```

(first parameter is the initial position, the second is the length sliced).
Second parameter defaults to end of string (string::npos).

Answer (score 9):

It looks like C++20 will have Ranges
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges
which are designed to provide, amongst other things, python-like slicing
http://ericniebler.com/2014/12/07/a-slice-of-python-in-c/
So I'm waiting for it to land in my favorite compiler, and meanwhile use
https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/

Answer (score 7):

```
std::string text = "Apple Pear Orange";
std::cout << std::string(text.begin() + 6, text.end()) << std::endl;  // No range checking at all.
std::cout << text.substr(6) << std::endl; // Throws an exception if string isn't long enough.
```

Note that unlike python, the first doesn't do range checking: Your input string needs to be long enough. Depending on your end-use for the slice there may be other alternatives as well (such as using an iterator range directly instead of making a copy like I do here).

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/):

```
std::string text = "Apple Pear Orange";
std::cout << text.substr(6, std::string::npos) << std::endl; // "Pear Orange"
```

Here [string::npos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) is synonymous with "until the end of the string" (and is also default but I included it for clarity).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using the string class:

```
std::string text = "Apple Pear Orange";
size_t pos = text.find('Pear');
```

Answer (score 1):

**First parameter determines the starting index and the second parameter specifies the ending index remember that the starting of a string is from 0 **

```
string s="Apple";

string ans=s.substr(2);//ple

string ans1=s.substr(2,3)//pl
```